# retrieve id's from selected checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have some checkboxes and I want to retrieve in idList the list of id's coresponding to the selected checkboxes.

This is my code:

```
@foreach (var inv in Model.Invoices)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.CheckBox("Selected", true, new { @class = "SelectInvoice", data_id = inv.ID, id = "Selected-" + inv.ID })</td>
```

For now I get all the id's from the model:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SendUnpaid", "Invoice"))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("idList", string.Join(",", Model.Invoices.Select(row => row.ID)))
```

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would prefer to do that. IMO cleaner and easier to maintain.

Suppose you have a list of invoices in your model.

**Model**

```
public class YourModel
{
public string Property {get; set;}
public IList<Invoice> Invoices {get; set;}
}
```

Create custom class for Invoice

```
  public class Invoice
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Invoices.Count; i++) 
    { <tr> 
      <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Invoices[i].IsChecked, new { @id = Model.Invoices[i].Id}) <span>@Model.Invoices[i].Name</span> 
     </td> 
     </tr> 
    }
```

**Controller**

Get your list of Id's or do whatever you like with the checked items.

```
 foreach (Invoice invoiceObj in model.Invoices)
           {
              if (invoiceObj .IsChecked)
              {
              }
           }
```

To check items on load, you would fill your invoice list on GET action method and pass it to the view.